# Reusable Ajax call in X times with same logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation, symfony-forms

This is very **bad** code

I need to do similar logic but without setInterval.

There is foundation 5 modal dialog

```
<span class="spanButton registration" data-reveal-id="addExternalRegistration">Add external registration</span>
```

This button that reveal empty modal

```
<div id="addExternalRegistration" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-hidden="true">
```

and with jQuery I am fill dialog with form.

In Ajax success I change content in dialog if form has errors. 
And story ends here. But I need to cover x submits before form is valid.

setInterval kills memory I know that, this is just example to show what I want.

**response** is new form with errors and should not be sumbited, it is need to send ajax request and all that in x circles.

```
$('.registration').click(function () {
            $('#addExternalRegistration').load("/dashboard/add-external-registration/{{ confName }}");

            setInterval(function () {
                $('form[name="dashboard_conference_registration_form"]').on('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/dashboard/add-external-registration/{{ confName }}',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            $('#addExternalRegistration').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 3000);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do some old tricks.

**recursive calls**

This is function that sends ajax request unlimited number of time

> **(in theory because of leak of memory, unfortunately).**

```
var ajax = function () {
            $('form[name="dashboard_conference_registration_form"]').on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/dashboard/add-external-registration/{{ confName }}',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#addExternalRegistration').html(function () {
                            return response;
                        });
                        setTimeout(ajax(), 2000);

                    }
                });
            });
        };
```

Then I call recursive function that fires recursion on submit.

```
        $('.registration').click(function () {
            $('#addExternalRegistration').load("/dashboard/add-external-registration/{{ confName }}",
                    // Wait until form is loaded at modal window
                    // And then do the logic
                    function () {
                        $('form[name="dashboard_conference_registration_form"]').on('submit', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();

                            $.ajax({
                                url: '/dashboard/add-external-registration/{{ confName }}',
                                method: 'POST',
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                success: function(response) {
                                    $('#addExternalRegistration').html(function () {
                                        return response;
                                    });
                                    setTimeout(ajax(), 2000);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
            );

        });
```